# File size is getting progressively larger as I continue to download data

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am downloading financial data using to_hdf and I have noticed that each file gets larger and larger as it keeps downloading. What is happening?

The first file was saved as 223 KB and the most recent where I stopped (67) was saved as 14,609 KB.

The following is the code (some sections that are irrelevant have been removed):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
from pathlib import Path
import os.path


def main():
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    start = end + dt.timedelta(days=-5)

    dr = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end)
    cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
    holidays = cal.holidays(start=dr.min(), end=dr.max())
    a = dr[~dr.isin(holidays)] # not US holiday
    b = a[a.weekday != 5]
    b = b[b.weekday != 6]

    for year in set(b.year):
        tmp = b[b.year == year]
        for week in set(pd.Index(tmp.isocalendar().week)):
            temp = tmp[pd.Index(tmp.isocalendar().week) == week]
            start = temp[temp.weekday == temp.weekday.min()][0]  # beginning of week
            end = temp[temp.weekday == temp.weekday.max()][0]  # ending of week

    # get list of all index tickers
    ticker_strings = si.tickers_sp500()

    data_dir = 'data'

    x = 1

    tickers_dir = './tickers'

    Index = '^GSPC'

    # initialize list for the following f(x)
    Df_list = list()

    ticker_data(ticker_strings, start, end, Df_list, data_dir, x)

    print("Complete")


def ticker_data(ticker_strings, start, end, Df_list, data_dir, x):
    # find values for individual stocks
    for ticker in ticker_strings:
        loc_start = start
        while loc_start <= end:
            period_end = loc_start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
            intra_day_data = yf.download(ticker, loc_start, period_end, period="1d", interval="1m")
            extra_day_data = yf.download(ticker, loc_start, period_end, period="1d", interval="1m", prepost=True)
            Df_list.append(intra_day_data)
            Df_list.append(extra_day_data)
            loc_start = loc_start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        df = pd.concat(Df_list)

        # creates file name
        filename = end.strftime('%F') + " " + ticker + ".h5"
        # saves file name to folder
        df.to_hdf(os.path.join(data_dir, filename), mode='w', key='df')
        #df.to_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, filename))

        print(x, ticker)
        x += 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: More data necessarily takes up more space. So if you download more and push more to file the file size will necessarily grow. Is this the question you intend to ask? If you 'consolidate' the data using statistics, you can get a constant file size at the expense of losing the precise data you've downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending new data to `Df_list` at every iteration of `for ticker in ticker_strings` and you are saving all of that every time. Which means that every file will contain also the previous file's data.

You should use a variable local to the `for ticker in ticker_strings` loop instead of using a list passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

This could be because it is constantly downloading new data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).